# Django Auth, Users and Permissions

Tags: django, permissions

I have a **Organization** and **Employee** models

```
class Organization(models.Model):

    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    name = models.CharField(u'Name', max_length = 255)
    ...

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    ...
```

Will it be good if I use **AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE**, so Employee becomes user profile?

This way I can use Django permission system to set employees permissions, like

- can see all documents
- can see own organization documents
- can see his own documents

Is is OK to have a permissions that are not a global one like "**can see all documents**"?

And what If I also want to have a permissions per Organization? How to do this? And how to distinguish permissions per Organization and per Employee?

Edit: I'm using Django 1.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, yes, you're ok.

Because:

1) Using AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE=Employee will make Employee instance to be available for instance in this way:

```
def view(request):
    employee_instance = request.user.get_profile()
```

2) Using custom permissions is easy, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#custom-permissions

Edit:

having custom permissions on organizations is possible as well, probably best if you create permissions programatically, like mentioned in the manual, this way:

```
content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='myapp', model='Organization')
permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_do_something', name='Can Do something',
                                       content_type=content_type)
```

now, you have permission aware organization model, you just assign it to your user.

To clarify more:

Django auth system is sort of a fixed ACL. You assign roles to a user (or group) and that's pretty much it. Django offers helper wrapper function to easily filter out users who don't have a given permission. If you need to decide at runtime and/or in more generic way, whether an object has permission to do something, you either need full blown ACL system (and which django.auth is not) or you code that kind of behavior yourself. This depends on your needs and obviously on the need to manage those permissions. In the OP's case, the behavior is fixed, therefore I would recommend just coding this in and be happy. But the needs may vary and so does the solution. Django auth is good at assigning static permissions to user, gropu or a "profile" object. What that means to your app is up to you in the end.

So in this case, the good solution would be to have a fixed set of permissions like "can view own documents" or "can view organization documents" that is assigned to user/group. And you app should decide, what it means and serve documents accordingly, taking either runtime state in the account or using models structure to determine the proper data set to serve.

Comment: What about permissions per Organization then?

Comment: Not sure whether we're on the same page here. You need separate permission tree on your organization? If that is so, django auth won't support this kind of behavior out of the box, as django.contrib.auth is targeted at user logins and their permissions. On the other hand, creating permission system for any other model should not be complicated. It's just many-to-many and I would create a simple annotation helper to check for organization permissions.

Comment: I need permissions which apply for companies, and not for users. Do I need a separate permission tree for this?

Comment: Well the permission system used by django is static by nature. It seems to me that you need to assess users permission to access any given document at runtime -- based on whether the user belongs to a organization or not. That is not something I would use permission system for. AFAIK you need to code this yourself. Or better yet, you use static permissions for thinks like: that user is a manager, he sees everything, that user is an employee, he sees only his own documents. And at runtime, based on this "global" permission, you decide wchich documents to display.

Comment: Is it better to use groups for "Manager" and "Employee" and 'Can see everithing', 'can see his own documents' for permissions? And in which case it's not good to use Django permission system?

Comment: Groups would be fine in this case IMHO. As for in which case is not good to use django.auth, well, if you need full blown ACL for instance, or on the other end of the spectrum, it might be too heavy sometimes. It really depends on what you want to achieve. And more to the point, how you need to manage your permissions

Comment: Thank you. Can you edit your answer to reflect your comments?